# What error does "unexpected tIVAR, expecting $end" point to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am just trying to enter the command `$ rvm use 1.9.3@rails3tutorial2ndEd --create --default` into interactive Ruby (command taken from Michael Hartl's tutorial).

I keep getting error messages about an unexpected tIVAR.  After several attempts to tweak the command, I seem to have pared the error message down to:  `syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting $end.`  So now what?

Answer (score 1):

tIVAR means instance variable, the extra part means you're missing an 'end'

end starts with do :)

Answer (score 0):

rvm is not a Ruby or Rails command.  Run the command in the directory that is the root of your app.